# Does dynamic class loading through Class.forName work with simple Class names

Tags: java, classnotfoundexception, dynamic-class-loaders

I tried dynamic loading of classes in a simple program and intrestingly when ever i try dynamic loading of classes with simple name it fails with classnotfoundexception. this happends only if the classes are under a package other than default package.

But when i specify the full path name, the dynamic loading succeeds. The class being loaded is in the same package as the Main class.

File Main.java:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException {                  
        System.out.println(Class.forName("m"));
    }
}

class m extends Main{
}
```

Comment: Then haven't you obviously answered your own question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `Class.forName` *always* needs the package-qualified class name. From the [parameter documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29):

> `className` - the fully qualified name of the desired class.

The package of the calling code is irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but can you tell me the reason behind such a restriction. My guess is could it be to avoid the collision between classes from multiple packages?

Answer (score 0):

You have to put fully qualified class name for the Class here

such as `System.out.println(Class.forName("com.sample.M"));`

assuming

com.sample is your class package name.